# Can we have a feature to Invite to askubuntu?

Tags: feature-request

I'm not sure how anyone else feels about it, but I do want to know: Do we want, and can we have a feature for officially sending invites to join the askubuntu community?

Comment: "Hey, you should check out [ubuntu.SE]! They help with all of the problems!" Anybody can already join without limit, so I don't see why an explicit invite (especially one done by the site, not a user) is necessary.

Comment: I do see your point. But flashy is nice, sometimes... Your exact words would make a great predefined invite message. Especially the "they help with all of the problems"

Comment: How would this work? If you are making a `feture-request` then you need to give examples of how this would work. How are you going to invite someone who is not already a member? We can't even send privert messages to each other here, so how would that work?